# Regex sub only removes certain expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm running a program which creates product labels based on csv data. The function which I am struggling with takes a data structure which consists of a number combination(width of a wooden plank) and a string (name of product). Possible combinations I search for are as follows:

5 MAPLE PEPPER-ANTIQUE

3-1/4 MAPLE CUMIN-ANTIQUE

2-1/4+4-1/4 MAPLE TIMBERWOLF

My function needs to take in the data, split the width from the name and return them both as separate variables as follows:

```
desc = row[1]
if filter.lower() in desc.lower():
    size = re.search(r'(\d{1})(\-*)(\d{0,1})(\/*)(\d{0,2})(\+*)(\d{0,1})(\-*)(\d{0,1})(\/*)(\d{0,2})', desc)
    if size:
        # remove size from description
        desc = re.sub(size.group(), '', desc)
        size = size.group() # extract match from obj
    else:
        size = "None"
```

The function does as intended with the first two samples, however when it comes across the last product, it recognizes the size but does not remove it from description. Screen shot below shows the output after I print (size + \n + desc)

[image: OUTPUT]

Is there an issue with my re expression or elsewhere?
Thanks

Comment: `\d+(?:(?:-\d+\/\d+)(?:\+\d+(?:-\d+\/\d+))?)?` is really the same thing but shorter... Plus it corrects `*` to `?`, which I assume is what you want so that you don't get `---` or `+++++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub()` expects its first argument to be a regex. It works for the first two because they don't contain any characters that have special meaning in the context, however the third contains `+`, which is special.

There's not actually any reason to use regex there... regular string replacement should work:

```
desc = desc.replace(size.group(), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why replace and not simply match what you need?

```
import re 

text = """5 MAPLE PEPPER-ANTIQUE 
3-1/4 MAPLE CUMIN-ANTIQUE 
2-1/4+4-1/4 MAPLE TIMBERWOLF""".split('\n')

print(text)

for t in text: 
    pattern = r'(?P<size>[0-9-+/]+) *(?P<species>[^0123456789]*)'
    m = re.search(pattern,t)
    print(m.group('size'))
    print(m.group('species'))
```

Output:

```
5
MAPLE PEPPER-ANTIQUE 
3-1/4
MAPLE CUMIN-ANTIQUE 
2-1/4+4-1/4
MAPLE TIMBERWOLF
```

Regex:

```
r'(?P<size>[0-9-+/]+) *(?P<species>[^0123456789]*)'
2 named groups, between them 0-n spaces.
1st group only 0123456789-+/ allowed
2nd group any but 0123456789 allowed
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and is helpful however the other solution solved the issue with less code adjustment.